# In MySQL date intervals, is 1 MONTH the same as 30 DAY? Is 1 QUARTER the same as 3 MONTH? And so on?

Tags: mysql, date, intervals

I am trying to write a PHP script that will process recurring payments every month, quarter, year, etc. This script will run as a nightly Cron job.

I don't want to run into a situation where somebody subscribes, say, on the 15th of a January, and then gets billed again on the 1st of February.

Is that what would happen if I checked the last payment against INTERVAL 1 MONTH? Or would it be the same as INTERVAL 30 DAY, and only process the payment again on the 15th of February, which is what I want?

Comment: It's be pretty easy to test it yourself...

Comment: Seriously. It takes less time than asking the question.

Comment: I agree that you should be able to test this yourself. When doing so, though, be sure you try different months so you can see how months with a different number of days are handled. You might also want to see how subtracting an interval of `1 MONTH` from March 31st would work, for example. I would hope it's more useful than just being a synonym for `30 DAY`...

Answer (score 5):

Accroding to [MYSQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

> If you add MONTH, YEAR_MONTH, or YEAR and the resulting date has a day
>   that is larger than the maximum day for the new month, the day is
>   adjusted to the maximum days in the new month:
>
> mysql> SELECT DATE_ADD('2009-01-30', INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
>           -> '2009-02-28' Date arithmetic operations require complete dates and do not work with incomplete dates such as '2006-07-00' or
>   badly malformed dates:

Thus if you use the 1 month built in function you do not have to worry when the last day of the month is.  MYSQL does all the work for you.

Comment: what about in case of data_sub, SELECT DATE_SUB('2009-02-28', INTERVAL 1 MONTH); -> '2009-01-28' .... vice versa not correct

Comment: @Zigri2612 it was not one on one relation... the result would be '2009-01-28'